# Escaping double quotes in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, escaping

I'm trying to bind a value to my component but I have trouble escaping double quotes.

This is working:

```
<span>{{ config.pages["pageKey"].components[0].display }}</span>
```

But not that:

```
<MyComponent v-bind:componentConfig="config.pages[\"pageKey\"].components[0]" />
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried `<MyComponent v-bind:componentConfig='config.pages["pageKey"].components[0]' />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation.

It is more cleaner to use dot notation:

```
<MyComponent v-bind:componentConfig="config.pages.pageKey.components[0]" />
```

Answer (score 10):

Best idea is using `&quot;`

```
<MyComponent v-bind:componentConfig="config.pages[&quot;pageKey&quot;].components[0]" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use single quotes:

```
<MyComponent v-bind:componentConfig="config.pages['pageKey'].components[0]" />
```

or:

```
<MyComponent v-bind:componentConfig='config.pages["pageKey"].components[0]' />
```

Comment: First way is better. It's html :)

Comment: I would access to an object's properties by using the dot notation.. It is more clean

Comment: It a good idea. I simply corrected his mistake with the most little change